# How to prevent page load when calling a function on form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a function that I can reuse in different pages for searching Images.
and I don't want page to be refresh when hitting enter.

without form it is working fine on onclick event.

How can I prevent page from reloading ?

Here is the form below, Thank you.

```
<form method="post" action="#">
   <div class="input-group form-sm form-2 pl-0 m-b-20">
      <input class="form-control " id="image_keyword" type="text" >
      <div class="input-group-append">
         <button type="submit" class="input-group-text" onsubmit="searchImages()">search</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

JQuery function.

```
function searchImages()
{
    let keyword = jQuery("#image_keyword").val();
    let response = searchMedia('image',keyword);
    console.log(response);
    if(response.status === 'success')
    {
        // some code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `e.preventDefault()` and `addEventListener`

```js
function searchImages(e)
{
    e = e || window.event 
    e.preventDefault();
    let keyword = jQuery("#image_keyword").val();
    let response = searchMedia('image',keyword);
    console.log(response);
    if(response.status === 'success')
    {
        
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="#" onsubmit="searchImages(event)">
   <div class="input-group form-sm form-2 pl-0 m-b-20">
      <input class="form-control " id="image_keyword" type="text" >
      <div class="input-group-append">
         <button type="submit" class="input-group-text" >search</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to use my own function

Comment: Thank you, it worked but is there any other way to do same without using  document.querySelector ?

Comment: @Javed Saifi Ok not its working with `querySelecotor()`. Accept answer if it worked

Answer (score 2):

You need prevent the default behavior of `onsubmit` event.

```
function searchImages(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    let keyword = jQuery("#image_keyword").val();
    let response = searchMedia('image',keyword);
    console.log(response);
    if(response.status === 'success')
    {
        let data = response.data;
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: will you please tell how `e` will be passed to `searchImages`

Answer (score 1):

Use `onsubmit` function in `form` tag instead of `submit` button.And pass event param.The prevent using `e.preventDefault()`

```js
function searchImages(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  console.log('ok')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="#" onsubmit="searchImages(event)">
  <div class="input-group form-sm form-2 pl-0 m-b-20">
    <input class="form-control " id="image_keyword" type="text">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button type="submit" class="input-group-text" >search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

For Simple Jquery Approach .Define submit with in dom

```js
$('#form_one').on('submit',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  console.log('ok')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="#" id="form_one">
  <div class="input-group form-sm form-2 pl-0 m-b-20">
    <input class="form-control " id="image_keyword" type="text">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button type="submit" class="input-group-text" >search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the reload of page :
    use :
     event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

`<button type="submit" class="input-group-text" onsubmit="searchImages()">search</button>`

to

`<button type="button" class="input-group-text" onclick="searchImages()">search</button>`

No need to do anything else.